# Report Builder - Remove Zero's results from a bar graph

Tags: reporting-services

My last question had such great feedback that I thought I might ask another question. My thanks to those that viewed and responded last time.

I have a bar graph looking at the number of occurrences of an event. However in many cases there is a zero value because they didn't do it. But it muddles up the bar graph when I add data labels and there are a bunch of zeros.

Is there a way to remove these from the graph?

[image]

I am sorry if this is posted to the wrong group (still figuring out the tags to get it to the right spot).

Comment: You'll probably need to change your Value formula to something like `=IIF(SUM(Fields.NUMBER.Value) = 0, NOTHING, SUM(Fields.NUMBER.Value))` to replace the Zeroes with NULL values.

Comment: This is great thanks. this solves another problem I had (that i didn't know). I found the Zero thing in the datalabel properties.